# Route is not found -logout

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am trying to click on logout button, but it returns an error:

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

There's no `getLogout` in Authcontroller, and it worked before, not sure why now it isn't.

AuthController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Registration & Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
    | authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
    | a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
    |
    */

        use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;
        protected $redirectTo = "dashboard";
        protected $loginPath = 'auth/login';


    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'username' => 'required|max:20|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Routes.php:

```
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');
```

view:

```
  <a href="auth/logout">Logout</a>
```

Comment: `getLogout()` resides in the trait `AuthenticatesUsers` which is pulled in in the trait `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php#L18

Comment: Could you paste the full error into your question please. Is the route it cannot respond to definitely `auth/logout`?

Comment: @haakym yes. putting it in external paste link , can't paste here:

https://justpaste.it/uo39

Comment: Do php artisan route list

Comment: Try `<a href="/auth/logout">Logout</a>`

Comment: @sef4eg you were right! a fool I am to miss the ```/``` at the beginning.

Comment: Let's consider it as the answer lol

Comment: @geckob may I ask why you need the route list in this case?

here's the screenshot with the ```auth/logout``` after running it:
http://postimg.org/image/6314nsm63/

Comment: @sef4eg lol yes :) . Thanks!! regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<a href="/auth/logout">Logout</a>
```

Or give your route a name

```
Route::get('auth/logout', ['as' => 'logout', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');
```

and do

```
<a href="{{route('logout')}}">Logout</a>
```